# dxChart elevation from elevation service

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using the google elevation service to get my elevations,
and now I'm trying to chart them with dxChart, but I can't really find a way to map the data

this is what I now do for the map rendering:

```
$("#height-map").dxChart({
    dataSource: elevations,
    series: [{
        name: 'Elevation',
        valueField: 'elevatiion'
    }]
});
```

and this is how the elevations is filled:

```
elevator.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK && results[0]) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            elevations.push(results[i]);
        }
    } else {
        alert("Elevation service failed due to: " + status);
    }
});
```

is there any way to chart them without over complexing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elevations.length; i++){
    elevations[i].point = i;
}

$("#height-map").dxChart({
    dataSource: elevations,
    commonSeriesSettings: {
        argumentField: 'point'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Elevation',
        valueField: 'elevation'
    }]
});
```